# I have sail up command and in this process Ubuntu connection time out error occurs.[**I am new to docker**]

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu

As the documentation says for laravel sail
I did install the sail package,
Installed vendor via artisan.
then
$:./vendor/bin/sail up

and this error triggers that says connection times out! But my internet is working fine as it is! what might be the solution can anyone help me in this regard?

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/manpages/manpages_5.10-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb  Connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-dejavu/fonts-dejavu-core_2.37-2build1_all.deb  Connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.33-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb  Connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/manpages/manpages-dev_5.10-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb  Connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
```

[image: Problem Screenshot]

Comment: What happens if you try to access the urls directly via a web browser? Do they work?

Comment: This thread will probably get migrated to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) at some point as it will get better quality answers there.